# My node app gives diffrent output on my vps(debian) then on my local machine(windows)

Tags: javascript, jsdom

I have this piece of code:

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom');

jsdom.env("http://sunwell.pl/index.php?id=ranking&t=2vs2&r=1",
          ['//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js'],
    function(error, window){
      if(error) {console.log(error); return;}

      var $ = window.$.bind(window);
      var _ladder = [];

      $("#rankingtable tr").each(function(i, v){  
        console.log('one more...');
        _ladder[i] = [];
        $(this).children('td').each(function(ii, vv){
          _ladder[i][ii] = $(this).text();
        });
      });

      console.log(_ladder);

      window.close();
    }
);
```

http://pastebin.com/eS4xyDrD.

Which well, works perfectly fine on my local machine(Windows), giving the expected  'one more..' text a few times and then the full array.

The problem comes when I run it on my VPS(debian onboard) which outputs just an empty array. I checked if maybe my server could for some reasons not recive the jquery object or the site but everything seems just fine. I don't know how to fix this, thanks for any help I am pretty sure the issuse is banal.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you run into a Cloudflare Challenge page.

Try to output `window.document.title`, you should get a `Attention Required! | CloudFlare` in the <title>. You either need to find a way to solve the captcha, or get the site owner to whitelist your IP on Cloudflare.